# Unique id for each instance of component

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two forms on a single page that are identical and I'm looking to abstract it into its own component. But I need to have a different id for each form/component because there's jquery that gets the value of the textarea and the content is different. What is the right way of doing this? Can I attach an id when I create a new instance of the component?

Form.vue:

```
          <form
            @submit.stop.prevent="onFeedbackFormSubmit(activity)"
            id="new_feedback_form">
            <div>
              <div class="textarea-container">
                <textarea
                  placeholder="Leave some feedback"
                  @keyup="onFeedbackFormSubmit(activity)"
                  v-model="feedback"
                  name="entry[feedback]">
                </textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

form.js:

```
  submitForm(activity) {
    let $form = $("#new_feedback_form");
    let data = $form.serialize();
    let path = `/portfolio/${activity.record.id}`;

    // api patch request
    this.apiPatch({ data: data, path: path })
      .then(({ data }, status, xhr) => {
        this.$store.commit("current/OVERWRITE_RECORD", {
          type: "activity",
          childAttr: "feedback",
          data: data.feedback
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.generateError(e);
      });
  },
```

Main.vue:

```
<Form id="form1"></Form>
<Form id="form2"></Form>
```

Is this possible (or correct)?

Comment: Let me take a look at your jquery code which using this id, and maybe you don't need an id, you just need a dom element

Comment: @jacky i've added the jquery code above. what i'm trying to do is to get the value inside the form to make a patch request. If I have 2 instances of the Form component on the same page, will they "conflict"? Right now, if i add the id on the component at the Main.vue, i'm not able to get the value inside the textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ref property:

```
<form ref="form">
...
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(this.$refs.form).serialize();
```

but, why not to use v-model to get the values in Vue?

Comment: in this way,you'll not worry about conflict

Comment: yes you're right, i can also use v-model, since each instance of the component will not have the same form values.

Answer (score 2):

In [Vue document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Non-Prop-Attributes)

> While explicitly defined props are preferred for passing information
> to a child component, authors of component libraries can’t always
> foresee the contexts in which their components might be used. That’s
> why components can accept arbitrary attributes, which are added to the
> component’s root element.

You don't need to declare id attribute in Form.vue component

But if you want to use id as a property and refer to is as `this.id`, you should declare `id` as a props

Form.vue

```
<form :id="id"> <!--  don't pass id here -->
</form>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['id'] // we need to declare id here
}
</script>
```

and when submit form

```
submitForm(activity) {
  let $form = $("#" + this.id);
}
```

and in `Main.vue`

```
<Form id="form1"></Form>
<Form id="form2"></Form>
```

Comment: Fine using a non-prop attribute to define the ID at the parent level... but OP still needs to know that ID in their jQuery selector.

Comment: In component, you can declare `id` as a props then you can refer to it as `this.id`

Comment: I am glad you can find a proper solution to this OP's requirement. You should modify your answer accordingly so that it properly addresses OP's objective.